# How to fetch only the UUID by passing in the size of the disk?

Tags: linux, uuid, mount, fstab, blkid

I am trying to mount a disk using ansible automatically using the following command:

`fdisk -l | grep  "64G" | grep -Eo "/dev/sd."`

This outputs `/dev/sda1` and I am adding that to the `/etc/fstab/`. But I want to add the UUID instead.

Is there a method to fetch the UUID by passing the size of the disk?
(I have only 1 disk attached with 64G of size so it returns only one output, want to know how to fetch the UUID instead of `/dev/sda` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `blkid` command passing in a specific device - e.g. `blkid /dev/sda1`

or you can browse the directory `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`, which has the uuids represented as symbolic links to the device nodes e.g. `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep /dev/sda1`

with ansible though, I think you can access the uuids and the device tree from ansible facts, which are collected for each host and accessible under the `ansible_facts` dictionary

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts

so it may be possible to construct an ansible `when` [conditional clause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#playbooks-conditionals) against the `ansible_devices` and attach that to a mount task